# How to stop a process pool from converting my string to a float

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns (street-name, town, coordinates), the last column is set to an empty string and is meant to represent the co-ordinates (lat,lng) of a location.

I have a method in which values from the rest of the columns are used as arguments to return a value to be inserted into the coordinates column. Since I have over a hundred thousand rows and want this done as quickly as possible, I'm using a Process Pool to do this on many rows at the same time.

I use the 'to_records()' method of Pandas to convert each row to an object, pass in the object to a method, which sets the coordinates attribute of the object and then returns it.

```
rows = coordinate_df.to_records()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=50)
rows_with_coord = pool.map(geocode_worker, rows)
```

And my worker method is like this, passing the address columns to a method that returns a json object containing the lat and long of the location:

```
def geocode_worker(row):
    json_results = coordinates_method(row[3])

    coordinates = 'lat: '+str(json_results.json['lat'])+', lng: '+str(json_results.json['lng'])

    row[7] = str(coordinates)

    return row
```

My problem is running it as is gets me this error:

```
Exception Value:    could not convert string to float: 'lat: 37.802408, lng: -121.221302'
```

My intention is not to convert it to a float at all, I want it as a string in the defined format. Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT:**

dtypes for the dataframe itself

```
[127223 rows x 2 columns]
business_type     object
coordinates       object
full_address      object
website           object
status            object
name     object
view_count       float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please post `rows.dtype`. The `Exception` suggests that `rows.dtype[7]` is a floating-point dtype.

Comment: It returns as 'float64' when I do rows.dtype[7] but is instead 'object' in the dataframe itself. I have since tried converting the original column to string explicitly using 'coordinate_df['coordinates'] = coordinate_df['coordinates'].apply(str)' but getting the dtype for its respective index in the 'row' object keeps returning as float64